# How to do a distinct count of a metric using graphite datasource in grafana?

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have a metric that shows the state of a server. The values are integers and if the value is 0 (zero) then the server is stable, else it is unstable. And the graph we have is at a minute level. So, I want to show an aggregated value to know how many hours the server is unstable in the selected time range.

Lets say, if I select "Last 7 days" as the time duration...we have get X hours of instability of server.

And one more thing, I have a line graph (time series graph) that shows the state of server...but, the thing is when I select "Last 24 hours or 48 hours" I am getting the graph at a minute level...when I increase the duration to a quarter I am getting the graph for every 5 min or something like that....I understand it's aggregating the values....but does any body know how the grafana is doing the aggregation ??

I have tried "scaleToSeconds" function and "ConsolidateBy" functions and many more to first get the count of non zero value minutes, but no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to tackle this, there are 2 places that aggregation happens in this situation:

1. When you query for a time range longer than your raw retention interval and whisper returns aggregated data.  The aggregation method used here is defined in your carbon aggregation configuration.
2. When Grafana sends a query to Graphite it passes `maxDataPoints=<width of graph in pixels>`, and Graphite will perform aggregation to return at most that many points (because you don't have enough pixels to render more points than that).  The method used for this consolidation is controlled by the `consolidateBy` function.

It is possible for both of these to be used in the same query if you eg have a panel that queries 3 days worth of data and you store 2 days at 1-minute and 7 days at 5-minute intervals in whisper then you'd have 72 * 60 / 5 = 864 points from the 5-minute archive in whisper, but if your graph is only 500px wide then at runtime that would be consolidated down to 10-minute intervals and return 432 points.

So, if you want to always have access to the count then you can change your carbon configuration to use `sum` aggregation for those series (and remove the existing whisper files so new ones are created with the new aggregation config), and pass `consolidateBy('sum')` in your queries, and you'll always get the sum back for each interval.

That said, you can also address this at query time by multiplying the average back out to get a total (assuming that your whisper aggregation config is using `average`).  The simplest way to do that will be to `summarize` the data with `average` into buckets that match the longest aggregation interval you'll be querying, then `scale` those values by that interval to calculate the total number of minutes.  Finally, you'll want to use `consolidateBy('sum')` so that any runtime consolidation will work properly.

```
consolidateBy(scale(summarize(my.series, '10min', 'avg'), 60), 'sum')
```

With all of that said, you may want to consider reporting uptime in terms of percentages rather than raw minutes, in which case you can use the raw averages directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the value is zero (0), the server is healthy - what other values are reported while the server is unhealthy/unstable? If you're only reporting zero (healthy) or one (unhealthy), for example, then you could use the sumSeries function to get a count across multiple servers.

Some more information is needed here about the types of values the server is reporting in order to give you a better answer.

Grafana does aggregate - or consolidate - data typically by using the average aggregation function. [You can override this using the 'sum' aggregation in the consolidateBy function](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.consolidateBy).

To get a running calculation over time, you would most likely have to use the [summarize function](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) (also with the sum aggregation) and define the time period, e.g. 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week, and so on. You could take this a step further by combining this with a `time` template variable so that as the period grows/shrinks, the summarize period will increase/decrease accordingly.

Comment: Then other values can range any where from 1 to 50k (just a guess on the upper limit)...but it can be any positive value....do you have any idea @tony metricfire

Answer (score 0):

`consolidateBy` didn't work for me, so I went into "Query Options" and set "max data points" to -1 which meant that I got a value based on all datapoints